# How to dual boot Ubuntu 12 with Windows 8 and use Secure Boot?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-8

I have Asus G46vw notebook pre-installed with Windows 8 and Secure Boot.

I want to dual boot Windows 8 with Ubuntu 12 and use Secure Boot.

In order to actually have the BIOS recognize the USB drives to boot from (Have to USB boot) I have no choice but to disable Secure Boot and enable CSM in the BIOS. Then I can boot from the USB/SDcard.

There are several places I could install a bootloader onto - There are lots of Microsoft related partitions on the disc!

Also, if I install Ubuntu with Secure Boot disabled, and I activate it again, will Ubuntu (and Windows 8) work?